# Как в Postgresql смерджить массивы?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть поле типа ARRAY и требуется смерджить в один массив это значение в одной таблице где дублируется другое поле

```
    ID   |   NAME    |  VALUE |
----------------------------
 1   |   Test    |  [VALUE_1] |
 2   |   Test2   |  [VALUE_2] |
 1   |   Test2   |  [VALUE_8] |
 4   |   Test    |  [VALUE_5] |
 1   |   Test3   |  [VALUE_2] |
```

```
        ID   |   NAME    |  VALUE |
----------------------------
 1   |   Test    |  [VALUE_1, VALUE_5] |
 2   |   Test2   |  [VALUE_2, VALUE_8] |
 1   |   Test3   |  [VALUE_2] |
```

пробовал получить общее значение через json_agg(type), но потом не мог распарсить результат в массив

Comment: Используйте array_agg - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677463/how-to-merge-all-integer-arrays-from-all-records-into-single-array-in-postgres

Comment: создается объект из массивов, проверил тип созданного объекта , jsonb[]

Comment: Ещё можно https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html array_cat

Comment: Вы примеры реализации в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677463/how-to-merge-all-integer-arrays-from-all-records-into-single-array-in-postgres смотрели? - там есть принятый ответ

Comment: unnest() -> GROUP BY -> array_agg()

Comment: сорри,  у меня оказалось что не массив, а jsonb тип, и нужно было их смерджить(а там массив из объектов), а я не понимал почему для массива функции не работают)
    SELECT
         jsonb_agg(x.obj) FILTER ( WHERE (x.obj is not null )) AS merge_result
    FROM
        table cp LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(cp.type::jsonb) AS x(obj)  ON TRUE